# probability question, n guests in a bar put on shoes leaving the bar.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

n guests in a bar  put on shoes leaving the bar. Each guest cannot differentiate the difference between a left shoe and a right shoe, nor their own shoe ! Find the probability that each guest has put on their own pair of shoes. Answer (i don't get why there is need for the odd members in the product whatsoever.) $${2\over 2n}{1\over 2n-2}{2\over 2n-3}...={2^n\over(n!)^2}.$$ BTW this is what it says in the book i think there is a typo with the second member,i think it being $1\over 2n-1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problem:
Each of $n$ guests chooses a pair of shoes from $n$ pairs of shoes. What is probability that each guest chooses one right and one left shoe (not necessarily of each pair)?
Answer: 
$p=\frac {2^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}$.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, the guests know nothing about the shoes (i.e. they put them on while blindfolded or something), then there are basically $2 n$ "identical" shoes waiting to be put on.

Now, the probability that the first guest will put on the correct pair of shoes is $\displaystyle \frac 2 {2 n} \frac 1 {2 n - 1}$. Why is this so? The first term accounts for the probability that he will pick *either the left or the right* shoe of his own pair, while the second term is the probability that he will pick *the remaining shoe of his own pair*. You can easily continue in this manner, formally using the product rule, to obtain:

$$
\underbrace{\frac 2 {2 n} \frac 1 {2 n - 1}}_{\text{first guest}} \underbrace{\frac 2 {2 n - 2} \frac 1 {2 n - 3}}_{\text{second guest}} \cdots = \frac {2^n} {(2n)!}
$$